# Implement a generalized builder pattern in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I decided to use [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern to avoid long unnamed-arguments constructor, but I have a specific use case for it. I have a base class and some inherited class from it which all of them must be able to construct separately. Below show a pseudo-code explain my special use case:

```
class B
{
  int i;
  int j;
public:
  B& setI(int i) {this->i=i; return *this;}
  B& setJ(int j) {this->j=j; return *this;}
}

class I : public B
{
  int i2;
  int j2;
public:
  I& setI2(int i) {this->i2=i; return *this;}
  I& setJ2(int j) {this->j2=j; return *this;}
}
B b = B().setI(12).setJ(13); // ok
I i = I().setI(12).setJ(13).setI2(14).setJ2(15); // error the first and second function return B not I
```

The above code could not be compiled because the functions in B do not return a type of class I. A solution has been suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50429769/2335245), but it is limited and it is not possible to create the base class separately. 
I am using c++11 but it is possible to use another version of c++.

**Update:**

There is a solution to accept B as a argument of constructor of I, but in the real problem there is some layers of inheritance which using this solution is not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

We can have a `Builder` for the class `I`, which eventually assigns the properties of the class `I` and its base class `B`. The `Builder` should be friends with the class `I` so that we could access the protected members of the `Builder` and also we make sure that all the properties all available to the `Builder`.

Consider the class `B`:

```
class B {
protected:
  int first;
  int second;

public:
  int get_first() { return this->first; }

  int get_second() { return this->second; }
};
```

And, the class `I`:

```
class I : public B {
  int third;
  int fourth;

public:
  int get_third() { return this->third; }

  int get_fourth() { return this->fourth; }

  class Builder : public B {
    int third;
    int fourth;

  public:
    Builder &set_first(const int &first) {
      this->first = first;
      return *this;
    }

    Builder &set_second(const int &second) {
      this->second = second;
      return *this;
    }

    Builder &set_third(const int &third) {
      this->third = third;
      return *this;
    }

    Builder &set_fourth(const int &fourth) {
      this->fourth = fourth;
      return *this;
    }

    friend class I;
  };

  I(const Builder &builder);
};
```

Thus, it allows us to assign values to the properties:

```
I::I(const I::Builder &builder) {
  this->first = builder.first;
  this->second = builder.second;
  this->third = builder.third;
  this->fourth = builder.fourth;
}
```

**Example**

```
int main() {
  I::Builder builder;

  I i = builder.set_first(100).set_second(102);
  std::cout << "[sample 1] first: " << i.get_first() << "\n";
  std::cout << "[sample 1] second: " << i.get_second() << "\n";
  std::cout << "[sample 1] third: " << i.get_third() << "\n";
  std::cout << "[sample 1] fourth: " << i.get_fourth() << "\n";
  std::cout << "\n";

  i = builder.set_first(12).set_second(13).set_third(14).set_fourth(15);
  std::cout << "[sample 2] first: " << i.get_first() << "\n";
  std::cout << "[sample 2] second: " <<  i.get_second() << "\n";
  std::cout << "[sample 2] third: " << i.get_third() << "\n";
  std::cout << "[sample 2] fourth: " << i.get_fourth() << "\n";
  std::cout << "\n";

  i = builder.set_first(1).set_third(3);
  std::cout << "[sample 3] first: " << i.get_first() << "\n";
  std::cout << "[sample 3] second: " << i.get_second() << "\n";
  std::cout << "[sample 3] third: " << i.get_third() << "\n";
  std::cout << "[sample 3] fourth: " << i.get_fourth() << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
[sample 1] first: 100
[sample 1] second: 102
[sample 1] third: 0
[sample 1] fourth: 0

[sample 2] first: 12
[sample 2] second: 13
[sample 2] third: 14
[sample 2] fourth: 15

[sample 3] first: 1
[sample 3] second: 13
[sample 3] third: 3
[sample 3] fourth: 15
```